# Algebras and $\sigma$-algebras associated to random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $\{v_\lambda:~\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be a family of real-valued random variables on a (complete) probability space $(\Omega, \sigma, \mathbb{P})$. Assume the variables lie in $\bigcap_{p=1}^\infty L^p(\Omega)$ and denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the unital algebra generated by them (along with the constants), and $\alpha$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them (i.e. the minimal complete sub-sigma-algebra with respect to which they are measurable).

If the variables are Gaussian then it is a consequence of the Wiener chaos decomposition (see e.g. Janson - Gaussian Hilbert Spaces) that
$\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega, \alpha, \mathbb{P}|_\alpha)$. In particular, $L^2(\Omega,\alpha,\mathbb{P}|_\alpha)$ is generated by $\mathcal{A}$ as a subspace of
$L^2(\Omega, \sigma, \mathbb{P})$.

But what can we say in the general case? Is it possible that the algebra and $\sigma$-algebra generate different subspaces? Relevant references would be appreciated - mostly I'm having trouble searching for literature about actual algebras of random variables because the term '$\sigma$-algebra' appears almost everywhere.

Comment: I suppose the $\sigma$-algebra you refer to is the smallest sub-$\sigma$-algebra of measurable subsets of $\Omega$ relative to which all of the $\nu_\lambda$ are measurable functions.  Is that right?

Comment: When you say "the algebra they generate" do you intend to throw in the constants?  I am not sure if it is strictly necessary, but I think you need it if the Wiener chaos argument is going to work.

Comment: Edited to make these things a little clearer: but yes, the unital algebra and the minimal (complete) $\sigma$-algebra they generate.

Comment: If your random variables were in $L^\infty$ this would follow from the multiplicative system theorem.  There might be another version of it that works for unbounded functions, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look that up, might yield some generalisation :) - I am more interested in the unbounded case, as the Gaussian prototype suggests.

Comment: Ah, apparently it's false in general.  You get a counterexample with $\Omega = [0,\infty)$, $\mathbb{P} = e^{-x^\alpha}\,dx$, $0 < \alpha < 1/2$, and $\mathcal{A}$ the polynomials; then $\alpha = \sigma$ but $\mathcal{A}$ is not dense in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$; $\sin(x)$ is not in the closure.  References to references at http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-168-00/S0002-9947-1972-0294655-X/S0002-9947-1972-0294655-X.pdf ; if I find a reference I can read I will post an answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: This sounds like it's related to weighted polynomial approximation (though "approximation" here usually means uniform approximation), which is sometimes possible and sometimes it isn't. It would work for an exponential weight, so $\alpha<1$ is crucial here.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Yeah, from some references it seems like this phenomenon is well known in the approximation theory literature.  I added that tag so maybe more experts will see it.

Comment: @NateEldredge: My standard source for these things is Koosis, The logarithmic integral 1, and indeed I think one could finish the argument by quoting results from this book (Theorem VI D1 perhaps). In particular, in Section VI G, he assures us that essentially the same results are valid for approximation in $L^p$ as for uniform approximation (in my comment above I was concerned about this).

Comment: Thanks guys, this is great. The original paper by Polard https://www.jstor.org/stable/2031820?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents on the Bernstein approximation problem also gives details of adapting his proof to $L^p$, which I'll probably peruse tomorrow - but effectively solves my original question.

Comment: Though I do wonder if @NateEldredge's simple counterexample has a simple proof.